# How do I mask a fixed image?

Tags: scroll, element, z-index, fixed, masking

I'm new to coding, and trying to design my own website for the first time.  I'm trying to create a page with a fixed element in the center that changes as a user scrolls down the page.  Using the z-index, I want to make it pass underneath other elements and change appearance.  What I am looking for is a way to mask the element so that it only shows up when scrolling past the middle of the page, much like a mask in photoshop.

Thanks!